# How can I parse a list of quoted arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this text:

```
text = '"Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"'
```

I want to convert it to an array:

```
array = [
  "Friend", 
  "One, Two, Three", 
  "something else"
]
```

How can I do it in Ruby? Simple `split()` won't work, since `,` may be inside some elements (like in this example). Maybe there are some libraries for that?

Comment: Perhaps a CSV parser will do the trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression:

```
text = '"Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"'
text.scan(/\"([,\ \w]+)\"/).flatten
#=> ["Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `scan`.

```
text.scan(/"([^"]*)"/).flatten
# => ["Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"]
```

or

```
text.scan(/"[^"]*"/).map{|s| s[1...-1]}
# => ["Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"]
```

Or, you can go with `split`.

```
text[1...-1].split(/", "/)
# => ["Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's CSV parser won't like the space between elements in `", "`, but if you clear that out, you can use it.

```
> s = '"Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"'
> t = s.gsub(/",\s*"/, '","')
> CSV.parse t
=> [["Friend", "One, Two, Three", "something else"]]
```